# $2^{x^{\cos(x)}}\sqrt{\cos(x)}$ can you rearrange mathematically to ${\cos(x)}\sqrt2^{x^{\cos(x)}}$

Tags: trigonometry, logarithms

$2^{x^{\cos(x)}}\sqrt{\cos(x)}$ can you rearrange mathematically to ${\cos(x)}\sqrt2^{x^{\cos(x)}}$ if $x > 0$ and $\cos(x) > 0$

Comment: it doesn't work when $\cos (x)=+1$

Comment: @WW1 what if cos(x) = -1

Comment: @StevenTaschuk They appear to be different (though similar) functions to me

Comment: @PeterWoolfitt Look at the user's question history and tell me it's not a duplicate.

Comment: @StevenTaschuk Done, and it's not a duplicate.

Comment: @StevenTaschuk The user appears to have asked a lot of (fairly unclear) questions about similar functions, but this particular question is not a duplicate of the others. Here the user asks whether two particular functions are the same.

Comment: @PeterWoolfitt The user is dealing with one question, flailing on it, and their process for solving it is spinning off questions here.  We could, indeed, discuss which questions are technically duplicates of which others, but what's the point?  It's abusive and obnoxious conduct.  Let's not indulge it.

Comment: @PeterWoolfitt  Yes I was looking for roots of the function? $2^{x^{\cos(x)}}\sqrt{\cos(x)}$ if $cos(x) > 0$ $x > 0$

Answer (score 0):

They are not the same. To show so we note that that there is a problem at $x=2\pi$, because we have
$$2^{(2\pi)^{\cos(2\pi)}}\sqrt{\cos(2\pi)}=2^{2\pi}$$ 
while 
$$\cos(2\pi)\sqrt{2}^{(2\pi)^{\cos(2\pi)}}=\sqrt{2}^{(2\pi)}=2^{\pi}$$

For more evidence that these functions are not the same, here is part of a graph of the two functions.

[image: greph]

Comment: so how do you solve $2^{x^{\cos(x)}}\sqrt{\cos(x)}$ if  $x > 0$ and $cos(x) > 0$

Comment: @antares whoops, sorry I did not see your requirement $\cos(x)>0$. I'll give a different answer.

Comment: @antares I have updated the answer

Comment: @antares since that is not an equation, solving it doesn't seem to have a meaning. Are you looking for the roots of the function?

Comment: Yes I was looking for roots of the function?